# Vector Calculations in LISP

Tags: math, common-lisp, linear-algebra, scientific-computing

How can I perform vector calculations in lisp, such as magnitude of a vector, norm of a vector, distance (between two points), dot product, cross product, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are several libraries of bindings to Fortran linear algebra packages like LAPACK and BLAS, such as [LLA, the Lisp Linear Algebra library](http://github.com/tpapp/lla/).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [GSLL](http://common-lisp.net/project/gsll) (which includes an interface to BLAS), and the underlying grid system.  On the other hand, I agree with the above comment in that if the things you mention are all you need, then it's probably faster/easier to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Tamas Papp's [LLA](http://github.com/tpapp/lla/) library might have what you want.  He recently [announced](http://tkpapp.blogspot.com/2010/05/upgraded-array-element-types-and-pinned.html) that he plans a rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

All this stuff is incredibly straight-forward maths. Calculate it the way you would normally.

Comment: @Charles So what is the more performant way of doing a dot product? Because that's simple multiplying two numbers together. And cross product is only slightly more complicated than that. And magnitude of a vector, well, again it's a very trivial operation. Exactly what speed benefits are you implying the existence of?

Comment: What's the order of an N-dimensional cross-product?  It's more than "Slightly more complicated".  Applications of linear algebra tend to be of large dimension.

Comment: the more performant way of doing a dot product is the one that compiles down to the most efficient code.  Even though the same mathematical operations are being performed, two implementations of a dot product can easily differ by an order of magnitude or more in execution time.

Comment: @Charles: Fair enough, @Stephen: That's an incredibly useless comment.